# Is Arcgis Maps Free

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, esri-maps

I want to use ArcGIS Online in public web application

- does this require key?
- or any limit quota per day?
- or limit users or any pricing?

  For example I know that

  - Google maps with key is limited 2,500 requests per day
  - Bing maps is limited to 125,000 requests per year

Any information will be appreciated

Comment: This post is incredibly unclear

Comment: Your question should include a link to the reference documentation of your topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be free! You get 50 credits per month. 
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/credits

It really depends how you would like to use it. For more information regarding pricing - https://developers.arcgis.com/pricing/